# how do I make a replacement with ampersand "&" in vim?

Tags: vim, vi

As the title says. I want to replace, say "tabs", with the ampersand sign (&).

I use:

```
:%s/\t/&/g
```

and of course it doesn't work. I use vim on mac os x (if this makes a difference). Thanks!

Comment: this is particularly comedic when replacing `&amp;` with `&`  I thought some autocmd was trying to force valid html!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you sure it's the ampersand that's the problem? I got more complaints about the tab. Don't forget to escape it.

`:%s/\t/\&/g`

Comment: `:help sub-replace-special` will show you all the special sequences in a replacement.  Note that `'magic'` is set by default, for those that have differing behavior based on that option.

Comment: yes, the ampersand is the problem. Escaping it worked!

Comment: the ampersand will substitute for the query. it comes in handy with regular expressions. say you wanted to enclose all three digit numbers with parentheses, you could do `:%s/[0-9]\{3}/(&)/g`

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the ampersand is that it is a [regular expression metacharacter for backreferences](http://vimregex.com/#backreferences). The `&` character in the replacement part of the regular expression means "everything that was matched in the match-part of the expression".

So, for example if you had a file containing the following line:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Executing a vi command like `:s/jumps/a&b/` would result in the following line:

```
The quick brown fox ajumpsb over the lazy dog.
```

You can do the same thing using `:s/\(jumps\)/a\1b/` but that's a lot more typing.

Why is & useful, other than just an alias for e.g. `\1` in a simple match expression? Well, you can also do things like this: `:s/lazy \(dog\|cat\)/"&" is now "stupid \1"/`:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the "lazy dog" is now "stupid dog".
```

The expression would get very ugly if `&` were unavailable.

Comment: I probably should have added to this answer "and you you have to escape your & with a leading \, like this: `:%s/\t/\&/g`"