# Vim: replacing string a with string b containing '&' sign

Tags: search, vim, replace

I have many many lines of code containing expressions of the form "a && b".
Now, I want to add the expression '&& c', hence ending up with "a && b && c". Pretty straightforward actually.

But, when I do

```
:%s/b/b && c/gc
```

it apparently replaces the && signs with 'bb'. And this seems to be a vim feature.

Now my question: **Is there a work around for this?**
I really need to do this replacement.

Best,
Miriam

Comment: Just add a backslash before each ampersign on your command: `\&`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do I make a replacement with ampersand "&" in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862920/how-do-i-make-a-replacement-with-ampersand-in-vim)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+ampersand

Comment: @phd there are always badly learned foreign words to fix right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use backslashs to escape special symbols:

```
:%s/b/b \&\& c/gc
```

Answer (score 1):

In the replacement part of a substitution, `&` is a special character that means "the whole match". It is typically used in scenarios where you are fine with the match itself and only want to add something to it:

```
:%s/foo/&bar/g
```

will turn every `foo` in the buffer into `foobar`.

In your case, `&` represents `b` so:

```
:%s/b/b && c/gc
```

gets you:

```
a && b bb c
```

All you need to do is escape the `&`:

```
:%s/b/b \&\& c/gc
```

and maybe, since we are at it, use `&` for what it is supposed to be used:

```
:%s/b/& \&\& c/gc
```