# Replacing HTML tags for plain tags does not work for me properly

Tags: html, vim

so I have tried to replace `<` an angle bracket with `&lt;` mark, so I could simply display plain HTML tags on my webpage, however when I do the following:

1. Visually select the line where I want to replace the bracket by pressing `V`
2. Then I try to type: `s/</&lt;/g`
3. The problem is It will keep the first bracket on place and Its adds `lt;` only

But I would want to replace the bracket in full, not just add `lt;` mark, because that wont display the plain HTML tags in the browser.

PLEASE CHECK THE SCREENSHOT FOR FURTHER REFFERENCES.

Why does not work? What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: `&` in replace string is a [magic character](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#sub-replace-special).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31862977/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+ampersand

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

From `:help :s`:

```
[...]
{string} can be a literal string, or something
special; see |sub-replace-special|.
[...]
```

Then, from `:help sub-replace-special` (slightly edited to reduce noise):

```
[...]
Otherwise these characters in {string} have a special meaning:
  &   replaced with the whole matched pattern
 \&   replaced with &
[...]
```

This means that `&` is a special character that is supposed to be used in the "replacement" part of a substitution to reuse the whole match. In this case:

```
:s/</&lt;/g
```

the whole match is `<` and the replacement is thus `<lt;`.

In order to use a literal `&` in the replacement, you must escape it:

```
:s/</\&lt;/g
```